# Fixed Element on scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm trying to reproduce the main scrolling effect on this beautiful portfolio: http://melaniedaveid.com/

I've followed this tutorial on Codyhouse: http://codyhouse.co/gem/fixed-background-effect/

And came up with the following Javascript function.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    contentright1 = document.getElementById('contentright1');

function checkScroll(id) {
    var offset = scrollTop - $(id).offset().top;

    if (offset >= 0 && offset < windowHeight) {
        $(id).addClass('fixed_content');

        if ((scrollTop/2) <= windowHeight) {
            $(id).removeClass('fixed_content');

        }
    }
    else {
        $(id).removeClass('fixed_content');
    }
};

checkScroll(contentright1);
```

The fidex_content class apply the following CSS:

```
.fixed_content {
position: fixed;
top:0; }
```

As you can see, my main problem is that I can't manage to remove this class when I go back to the position of the element in the first place.

Comment: interesting....can you mock something up on codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is a quick pen of it: http://codepen.io/PierrickGT/pen/pJvMvw